# Javafx tableview with data from multiple classes

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn, observablelist

I have no problem filling my tableview with diffrent data from 1 class. But it does not work for me with multiple classes. Any idea how to solve that?
I have checked out similar questions on stackoverflow. But none of them could help me. If you suggest anything with the "Callback" class, please provide me the full import, because there are a couple of Callback classes out there.

```java
public class MainViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TaskControl, Boolean> colErledigt;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TaskControl, Character> colPrioritaet;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TaskControl, String> colBeschreibung;


    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ProjectControl, String> colProjekt;


    @FXML
    private TableView<TaskControl> tblView;





    public final void initialize(final URL location,
            final ResourceBundle resources) {

        initializeTableElements();

    }


    public final void initializeTableElements() {
        colBeschreibung
                .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));

        colPrioritaet
                .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priority"));


        colProjekt.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));


        colErledigt.setMaxWidth(50);
        colErledigt.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<TaskControl, Boolean>("isDone"));
        colErledigt
                .setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(colErledigt));
        colErledigt.setEditable(true);

        try {
            tblView.setItems(getObsTasks());
        } catch (IDNotValidException | StringNotValidException e1) {
            System.out.print("FEHLER beim getObsTasks");
        }

        tblView.setEditable(true);
    }


    public ObservableList<TaskControl> getObsTasks()
            throws IDNotValidException, StringNotValidException {

        ObservableList<TaskControl> obsTasks = FXCollections
                .observableArrayList();

        Map<Context, Set<Task>> test = TasksContextUtility.INSTANCE
                .getAllContextsAndTasks();

        test.values().forEach(v -> {
            v.forEach(b -> obsTasks.add((TaskControl) b));
        });

        return obsTasks;
    }
```

Further question: How can I show a certain Attribute of an Instance in a HashSet in a TableCell. So I have in my TaskControl class a HashSet. In that HashSet there are Instances of the class "ProjectControl". Every instance of ProjectControl has attributes like "name" or "id" etc.

And I want to represent all the names of the project instances in 1 single table cell if possible. Maybe as a string seperated with commas (project1,project2,project3...).

Task class (shortened a lot) my TaskControl Class inherits from this class

```
public abstract class Task
  implements Serializable, IDValidatable
{
  private int id;
  private char priority = ' ';
  private final Set<Project> projects = new HashSet();

  public Task(int oid)
    throws IDNotValidException
  {
    if (isIDValid(oid)) {
      this.id = oid;
    } else {
      throw new IDNotValidException("The ID you have specified is not valid!")
      {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 99044660889990790L;
      };
    }
  }

  public final void setId(int oid)
    throws IDNotValidException
  {
    if (isIDValid(oid)) {
      this.id = oid;
    } else {
      throw new IDNotValidException("The ID you have specified is not valid!")
      {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 99044660889990790L;
      };
    }
  }

  public final int getId()
  {
    return this.id;
  }

  public final Collection<Context> getContexts()
  {
    return this.contexts;
  }

  public final void addContext(Context context)
    throws ContextNotValidException
  {
    this.contexts.add(context);
  }

  public final void removeContext(Context context)
    throws ContextNotValidException
  {
    this.contexts.remove(context);
  }

  public final Collection<Project> getProjects()
  {
    return this.projects;
  }

  public final void addProject(Project project)
    throws ProjectNotValidException
  {
    this.projects.add(project);
  }

  public final void removeProject(Project project)
    throws ProjectNotValidException
  {
    this.projects.remove(project);
  }

  public final Map<String, String> getAddons()
  {
    return this.addons;
  }
}
```

Comment: a `TableView` is designed to display rows of one type. If you need data from various types, I think your best option is to make a wrapper class that has the two instances as fields, and exposes all the properties you want in your table.

Comment: If the type of your `TableView` is `TaskControl`, then every row, as @sillyfly says, must contain an item of type `TaskControl`. The two types for the `TableColumn` are, in order, the type of the item in the row, and the type of the item in each cell of the column. So the first type in the `TableColumn` **must** match the type of the `TableView`: nothing else makes any sense. Why do you want to make different columns have different types of row item?

Comment: Thanks guys! Now I am way closer to solve this. Here is the new situation. I have a Set of instances of my ProjectControl class in my TaskControl class. And I need to represent the "name" attribute of every of those instances. Can a TableCell represent that?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the code relevant to that?

Comment: Done. If you need more code, let me know.

Comment: So I guess it's not really clear to me what you're trying to do. (I'm guessing that `ProjectControl` and `ContextControl` are subclasses of `Project` and `Context`, respectively.) Each row in your table is a visualization of a `TaskControl` (because you declare it as a `TableView<TaskControl>`). So each cell must show some property of, or at least some value derived from, a single `TaskControl` (because each cell is in a single row). So, for example, what are you expecting to see in a cell in the `colKontext` column?

Comment: You got it right. Project-/ContextControl inherits from Project/Context. In the colKontext column I expect to have all the name attributes of the contexts for this task. I also edited my question where I explain it a little more detailed.

Comment: So what's wrong with `TableColumn<TaskControl, Collection<Context>> colKontext ;` and `colKontext.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("contexts"));`? You can additionally use a `cellFactory` on the column if you need to customize the display.

Comment: @James_D Sorry, I was pretty busy. Tried it out now, with projects though. It fills my project column with something like "[todomanager.model.ProjectControl@1e1]".  The projects collection contains instances of project. But I need the name attribute from every single one of those instances.

Comment: You need to use a `cellFactory` to configure how it displays the result. (In addition to the `cellValueFactory`). I'll try to post something more specific when I'm back at my computer

Comment: I found my own solution, but I would really apprecciate it if you could post your solution with the cellFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding an additional String to my TaskControl, that contains the names of all the projects it contains. It gets the names through a function that I call just before I create the ObservableList for the Table Column.

```
private String projectsAsString;
    ...
public final void convertProjectsToString() {

    String projects = "";

    for (Project p : this.getProjects()) {
        ProjectControl pp = (ProjectControl) p;
        projects += pp.getName() + ", ";
    }
    if (projects != null && projects != "" && projects.length() > 4) {
        projects = projects.substring(0, projects.length() - 2);
    }
    this.projectsAsString = projects;
}
```

Thank you guys anyways for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opition you only have one nice solution for this.

You need a extra Class that holds your TaskControl, ContextControl and ProjectControl.

Your Code can look something like that.

```
class Wrapper{
 private TaskControl taskControl;
 private ContextControl contextControl;
 private ProjectControl projectControl;
 ...
 public Boolean isDone(){
   return taskControl != null ? taskControl.isDone() : null;
  }
}


@FXML
private TableView<Wrapper> tblView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Wrapper, Boolean> colErledigt;

colErledigt.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Wrapper, Boolean>("isDone"));
```

Comment: The correct property name to pass to the factory is `"done"`, not `"isDone"`. Otherwise `PropertyValueFactory` would be looking for `getIsDone` or `isIsDone` or `isDoneProperty` methods...