# TableView for different models

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to achieve the following in a TableView:

```
prod_name | prod_comment | ... | kcal | kjoule |
--------------------------------------------
name      |  hi          |     | 1.5  |   5 
name      |  hi          |     | 2.0  |   7
```

These are the models I work with:

```
Product (holds things like name,comment etc)
Nutrient (holds the kcal, kjoule strings etc)
Product_Nutrient (holds the amounts of kcal, kjoule etc for every product)
```

What I currently have is a DAO (and a seperate model) layer that joins all of these tables and returns them in the exact format as above, but for this project **its not allowed** to use SQL joins (school project). I didn't think this would become a problem, but now it is.

I've also tried to wrap the three models into one model as lists, but I'm not sure how to hold the relationships between the models, and how to then show them in a `TableView`. ([same as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34587101/5711524))

Let me know if anything is unclear so I can add more information.

EDIT;

For some clarification:

Some `Product` might not have every `Nutrient` in the `ProductNutrient`

eg:

```
prod_id | nutrient_id | amount |
1         1             0.0
1         2             5.1
2         1             1.4
3         1             0.2
3         2             0.0
```

Here `prod_id` 2 doesn't have `nutrient_id` 2 because `0.0` is something different than non existent.

EDIT:

Models:

```
public class ProductModel {

      private String name;
      private int prod_code;
      ....
      //getters/setters
}

public class ProductNutrientModel {

      private double amount; // amount of the nutrient linked to a product
      private int prod_code;
      private int nutrient_id; 
      ....
      //getters/setters
}

public class NutrientModel {

      private int nutrient_id; 
      private String name; // names of the nutrients
      ....
      // Nutrient holds no amount

      //getters/setters
}
```

Comment: The relationship between your model classes isn't really clear to me. Does `Product` have a reference to `ProductNutrient`? Or to `Nutrient`? Can you just post the code for those classes?

Comment: @James_D ProductNutrient represents the join table, it holds multiple p_id's and multiple nutrient_id's, with also the amount of that nutrient.

Comment: Each instance holds multiple ids for each of the other classes? I don't really get that. I would expect each `ProductNutrient` instance to reference a `Product` instance and a `Nutrient` instance. Again, can't you just post these classes in your question (or at least simplified versions of them that demonstrate the problem)?

Comment: @James_D they don't hold any instances of eachother at this moment, and I don't really know how to achieve that.

Comment: You effectively want each row in the `TableView` to represent something in the join table, is that correct? With columns displaying data from the corresponding product and from the corresponding nutrient?

Comment: @James_D Yes, I think. The Nutrient is nothing more than the 'name' which should be the header of a column. The ProductNutrient holds its actual value, which is linked to a product. (the product should also be visible in the row, with its nutrient values).

Answer (score 1):

I would define the classes as

```
public class Product {

    private int id ;

    private String name ;
    private String comment ;

    // constructor and get methods

}
```

```
public class Nutrient {

    private int id ;

    private String name ;
    private double kcal ;

    // ...
}
```

```
public class ProductNutrientContent {

    private Product product ;
    private Nutrient nutrient ;
    private double quantity ;

    // ...
}
```

The requirement that you can't use inner joins is pretty artificial, but you can just use three queries to get a list of `ProductNutrient` objects, as long as the database is not too large, as follows:

```
Map<Integer, Product> productsById ;
Map<Integer, Nutrient> nutrientsById ;
List<ProductNutientContent> productNutrientContents ;

// query product table, for each row in the result set do:
  Product product = new Product(/* data from result set row */);
  productsById.put(product.getId(), product);

// similarly populate nutrientsById...

// query join table, for each row in join table do:
  int productId = ... ; // productId from row in result set
  int nutrientId = ... ; // nutrientId from row in result set
  double quantity = ... ; // quantity from row in result set
  ProductNutrientContent content 
      = new ProductNutrientContent(productsById.get(productId), nutrientsById.get(nutrientId), quantity);
  productNutrientContents.add(content);
```

Now you can use your list to populate the table. For the table columns, just do the obvious thing:

```
TableColumn<ProductNutrientContent, String> productNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Product");
productNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getProduct().getName()));

TableColumn<ProductNutrientContent, Number> kcalColumn = new TableColumn<>("kcal");
kcalColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleDoubleProperty(cellData.getValue().getNutrient().getKcal()));

TableColumn<ProductNutrientContent, Number> quantityColumn = new TableColumn<>("Quantity");
quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleDoubleProperty(cellData.getValue().getQuantity());
```

Comment: There's one problem.. Nutrient has no 'value' of kcal, so in the above example I can't do `cellData.getValue().getNutrient().getKcal()` ? I don't get the`Quantity` column as its value should be under the `kcal` column.

Comment: @MeesKluivers Not sure I follow. Just modify it so it gets `kcal` from wherever it is actually stored.

Comment: the value is stored in the join table itself (in `ProductNutrientContent` in the solution above as `quantity` ), so should I just do `cellData.getValue().getQuantity()` for the `kcal` column?

Comment: With the above solution I'm still not getting the result I need. the  `cellData.getValue().getQuantity()` only gets the first it finds, but its not linked to the 'kcal' from Nutrient in this case, or to the product. I'm just getting the first quantities it finds in this case. I'll update my question to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: In your above example the `String name` in `Nutrient` is the 'column' (in the actual sql table) the `kcal` (and others) are stored, so the `double kcal` does not exist in my case.